# Magento 2 : How to end all active sessions for a customer?

Tags: magento2, customer-session

I was looking for possibility where i can give option to customer after password update to end all active sessions related to his account .

It would be helpful if can point in direction (even with a article link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found one post, hope it is helpful for you.

You'll have to create a custom module for that in my opinion. In that module you,

1. Create a customer attribute `login_expiry`, whose value is initially null.
2. Add a new value to the `customer_session` by calling the `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session::setData($name, $value)` method, called `logged_in_at`.
3. Write an observer for the `customer_login` event and set the `logged_in_at` value to the current timestamp.
4. Whenever user opts for "logout from all devices", set the `login_expiry` value of that customer to the current timestamp.
5. Write an observer for the `customer_session_init` event and there check if the `logged_in_at` value is less than `login_expiry`, logout the user.

Comment: Thank you for solution , i will try it a accept solution if that works for me . again thank you for your time

Comment: The solution worked fine , that you for your help

Comment: Good to hear. You're welcome.

Comment: @Sumit I tried to add condition on observer but getting error.  `Circular dependency: Magento\Customer\Model\Plugin\CustomerFlushFormKey depends on Magento\Customer\Model\Plugin\CustomerFlushFormKey and vice versa.`

Comment: @Sumit If we try to get `customerSession` object in `customer_session_init` event observer, we get `Circular dependency error`, and without `customerSession` Object how is it possible to logout the customer based on some condition as you have mentioned in point number 5 ?